# Generating data for logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic

Maybe I have to brush up on logistic regression but I'm trying to generate some fake data here using a binomial distribution and a vector of probabilities, fit a glm and then plot confidence intervals. It works but doesn't seem right ... the confidence bands are way too wide.

```
pr = c(0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.9,1,1,1)   
time <- 1:10
```

Comment: Your confidence bands *should* be wide if your underlying success probability is anything between 0.1 and 1.0. Do you truly only want to sample 10 observations? How should these be related to `time`?

Answer (score 2):

In logistic regression the data generating process is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_i | x_i &\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_i(x_i;\beta)) 
\\
p_i(x_i; \beta) &= \frac{e^{x_i^T\beta}}{1 + e^{x_i^T\beta}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Notice $P(y_i=1)$ depends on $x_i$ and $\beta$. Currently you are just setting $p(x_i;\beta)$ to some value. You need to fix a true $\beta$, calculate $x_i^T\beta$, and then get $p_i(x_i;\beta)$. For example

```
bet <- 2
x <- rnorm(10)
pr <- exp(x * bet) / (1 + exp(x * bet))
failures <- rbinom(10, 1, pr)
```

will give you data for $\beta = 2$.

Comment: Hi delimited,I'm still getting very poor confidence when I compute the confidence interval for my estimate is there any way I can increase this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate data rather than just probabilities. In your code, you have only 10 observations and you don't really have any probabilities, even though you've labeled one variable Pr.

The dependent variable should be a vector of 9's and 1's, and, it seems pretty likely that it should include a lot more than one observation for each level of your independent variable.

Rather than use hand-inputted vectors, you might want to use formulas and a random number generator for your DV.

Comment: Presumably "vector of 0's and 1's" rather than 9's!